# Is it possible to replace or customise the getUserMedia prompt?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm trying to add WebRTC video to a browser-based chat application, and I'd like to know if it's possible to customise the message box when calling getUserMedia() - see [this demo](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/) for an example. I've looked at [html5rocks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) and [the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia), and I don't see anything about this. So, is it possible for the browser's prompt to be replaced with e.g. a jQuery UI dialog widget?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't, due to security reasons.

The browser needs to make sure, that the user knows exactly what permission he is giving. If you could customise the prompt, you could make it look like it does something else, which would be very bad.

Comment: I suspected it wasn't possible - this clinched it.